# Call js method in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with class in js and how to call it in html file.

```js
class SetProp(){
  constructor(height,width){
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  function getHeight(){
    return this.height;
  }
  function getWidth(){
    return this.width;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="TryClass.js" type="text/javascript">
      prop = new SetProp(1000,1000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="prop.getWidth() " height="prop.getHeight();" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make canvas with 1000*1000 by using this method.
And need to pratices about using class.

Comment: do you use any template engine for rendering views?

Comment: i didn't use any template

Answer (score 2):

The html properties `width` and `height` cannot be assigned to functions, what you need to do is write a function that will return the width and height on  button click or after DOM load modify the attributes of your element with Javascript using Selectors as shown below:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').style.width =prop.getWidth() ;
document.getElementById('canvas').style.height =prop.getHeight() ;
```

Comment: now i see an error uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected identifier after  function getHeight(){

Comment: You only remove `function` key :

    `function getHeight() { ..` to `getHeight() {....`

and

    `function getWidth () {...` to `getWidth() {...`

Answer (score 0):

your getHeight() and getWidth() functions are private and dont asign to main class prototype so if you want access them you should use main class prototype like this:

```
'class SetProp(height,width){
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

}
 SetProp.prototype.getHeight=function(){
       return this.height;
  }
  SetProp.prototype.getWidth=function(){
       return this.width;
  }'
```